# What's happening at a molecular level to the resistance when the temperature of salt water is increased?

Tags: electricity, experimental-physics, temperature, electrical-resistance, conductors

What's happening to the electrical resistance at a molecular level when the temperature of a water with a bit of salt is increased? I noticed that the resistance decreases but in metals it is totally different and increases. I don't understand why is it different in metals and in solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Salty water is conducting because it salt ionizes in water, breaking into Na$^+$ and Cl$^-$ ions. The solubility of NaCl increases with increasing temperature (though not very strongly), as you can see from [this plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_equilibrium#/media/File:SolubilityVsTemperature.png). This means that at higher temperature more ions will be formed and therefore the resistivity will decrease (i.e. the conductivity will increase).

In a metal, resistivity is caused by scattering of the electrons with defects and vibrations (phonons) in the crystal lattice. If temperature is increased, the density of phonons and defects is increased, therefore the scattering events are more frequent. As a result, resistivity increases.

Comment: What about the conductivity of water at a *constant* concentration of NaCl?

Comment: @BertBarrois I am assuming that the concentration is constant. It is the solubility (how much of NaCl ionizes) that changes with temperature.

Comment: NaCl is not a weak electrolyte.  It is completely ionized when in solution.  I think I have a clue to the increasing conductivity: The viscosity of water decreases dramatically as the temperature increases.  This means that the aggregates are smaller.

Comment: The same is observed independent of concentration

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the mobility of the ions that increases with increase in temperature of the water? Well, I can't explain why the mobility increases but I am sure it does.

Comment: @AkarshGhale It's a possibility. The mechanism could be a reduction in water's viscosity, as suggested by Bert Barrios in the comment above.

Comment: If the drag on an ion can be modeled like the viscous drag on a macroscopic sphere -- a fraught extrapolation -- then ionic mobility should be inversely proportional to viscosity.

Answer (score -1):

The increase in temperature in water makes the separation of the nuclei in water  greater.  O is farther apart from H as temperature increases.  The respective electron clouds now occupy more space between the nuclei and less space elsewhere.  Therefore the nuclei are more visible and the partial charge $\delta$ increases. The water molecules now attract each other more strongly and come closer together.  Density thus increases.

Add salt.  Now more partial charge $\delta$ in the water dipole means more interaction with salt atoms. Solubility thus increases.

The  calculation sketch.  Use Hartree-Fock to obtain the electron orbitals of water molecule while minimizing the energy by adjusting nuclei separation.  obtain the charge distribution from the calculated wavefunctions and then the partial charge space-distribution.

Comment: While the mechanism described here may contribute to the increased conductivity, your text does not explain the increased conductivity.